# SQL Inner Join statement not giving desired results

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join

Hopefully someone can give me a hand here.   I have the following two tables:

```
Table: locations
location_id   user_id       city        state
1             1             Los Angeles CA  
2             1             New York    NY
3             1             Chicago     IL
4             2             Dallas      TX
5             3             Denver      CO
6             4             Miami       FL
7             5             Atlanta     GA

Table: events
event_id    user_id     event_name    event_date
1           1           My Event 1    2017-02-01
2           2           My Event 2    2017-03-01
3           3           My Event 3    2017-04-01
4           4           My Event 4    2017-05-01
5           5           My Event 5    2017-06-01
```

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT e.event_id,  e.user_id, e.event_name, e.event_date,
       l.user_id, l.city, l.state
FROM events e
INNER JOIN locations l
ON e.user_id = l.user_id
ORDER BY e.event_date ASC
```

I am trying just to get JUST the records in the events table, but also pull the corresponding city and state that match the user_id that both tables have in common.   The output should be:

```
 event_id   user_id     event_name    event_date    city          state
 1          1           My Event 1    2017-02-01    Los Angeles   CA
 2          2           My Event 2    2017-03-01    Dallas        TX
 3          3           My Event 3    2017-04-01    Denver        CO
 4          4           My Event 4    2017-05-01    Miami         FL
 5          5           My Event 5    2017-06-01    Atlanta       GA
```

Can anyone point me to my error in the SQL statement?

Comment: Which location for user_id = 1? Why Los Angeles in the result, why not New York?

Comment: Just need the first, and skip the rest that match the user_id

Comment: Define first (by data)

Comment: Where in the statement would that be?

Comment: That is not a statement, but a definition. Call it business rule if you wish. You, your manager, project manager or a business person should come up with it. The word 'first' means nothing unless the order of records in the same group is defined.

Comment: Sorry...  first, or ANY.  All I need here is to make sure that only ONE result comes up for each user_id in the statement.  It doesn't matter which.  So in the case of the example, Los Angeles, New York or Chicago can come up, as long as it is only ONE of them.  I know it doesn't make sense, but I am dealing with old stuff I need to work with right now, and this would solve the problem.

Comment: `GROUP BY event_id`, don't do any aggregation on city, the result is not predictable and may not consistent between two executions, but it will give you a random result (aka ANY). Note, that this is not ANSI compliant and won't work in other RDBMSs. If you need consistency between executions, use the MIN(location_id) as a join criteria, or a query similar to the on in @TimBiegeleisen 's answer.

Comment: SELECT e.event_id,  e.user_id, e.event_name, e.event_date,
       l.user_id, l.city, l.state
FROM events e
  INNER JOIN locations l
    ON e.user_id = l.user_id
GROUP BY e.event_id  
ORDER BY e.event_date ASC    - Doesn't work.  What am I missing?

Comment: Define not working, also moving to chat or using one of the upvoted answers would be a good idea, this conversation is getting a bit long for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never gave us the logic for deciding *which* location to choose for a given user.  One approach would be to take the minimum `location_id` associated with a given user:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       COALESCE(t2.city, 'NA'),
       COALESCE(t2.state, 'NA')
FROM events t1
LEFT JOIN locations t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MIN(location_id) AS min_location_id
    FROM locations
    GROUP BY user_id
) t3
    ON t2.user_id = t3.user_id AND
       t2.location_id = t3.min_location_id
```

Answer (score 1):

That's quite impossible, here the issue is for user with id `1` you have 3 tuples in the `locations` table , which city to select is the big question.

```
 1             1             Los Angeles CA  
 2             1             New York    NY
 3             1             Chicago     IL
```

Comment: I understand all of the issues, of course.  I should have been more clear.  Since there is no way of knowing,  I need to to make sure I grab the ONLY the FIRST matching instance and not additional instances.   So in this case, for user_id 1, it would only pull out Los Angeles CA.   Sorry, I am working with a structure put in place my someone else years ago :-(.